# Xamarin UITest C#: Calabash not properly linked

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitest

I am trying to test an Xcode iOS application using Xamarin UITest C#. I have gone through the steps listed here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/ and here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/ to set up my environment. I have verified that calabash is properly linked in by following the steps in the guide above, however I still get the error:

Setup: System.Exception : Unable to contact test backend running in app. A common cause is that the app is not properly linked with Calabash. Please verify that it includes the Calabash component.

I have tested the IPA by itself and it runs fine on a simulator and device.

Comment: This is normally caused by 1) Not including the UITest Nuget in your iOS project, 2) Not calling `Xamarin.Calabash.Start();` to start the agent within your app, 3) Using a release build instead of a debug build...

Comment: I think my issue is that the iOS app was not developed in Xamarin.iOS but in Xcode. I'm not sure how to add Xamarin.Calabash.Start() in the Xcode project successfully. If this were a Xamarin.iOS project, it would be easy. Can you shed any light on this?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Check out the Getting Started section of the Github repo for the iOS version of Calabash as that will walk you through the setup, once your iOS app is integrated with the Calabash framework, you can then write your `UITest`s in C#: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#getting-started

Comment: Hi, so what ended up fixing it for me was using the build that gets created in the Products folder in Xcode. I was using an Archived build previously. I double checked that the archive was debug and not release. I'm not sure why this worked, but it did.